# How to connect different tables from different systems having same database name?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

We are working with Laravel 5.2,
If a group of people is working on the same database, and have different tables for each person. We all have different views, controllers, routes, migration and everything. Then, how can we merge them and then make a single welcome page and connected different pages? It is actually working on different modules of same database.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Are you trying to merge completely different applications or are you all working on the same application locally but want to merge what each developer has done?

Comment: We are working on same application but each of us have it's different parts. Have different views eg. about us, contact us , join us page and are making a home page eg. welcome page. From where we can navigate anywhere. So, it's easy to make it on single system. but, if we are making it's different views, then how can we join them to make a single project.

Comment: Are you using any sort of version controller e.g. `GIT`?

Comment: No... should I?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you trying to do then yes. GIT will allow you to have one project/application that you can then "share" with all your developers. It provides a way to save the application in different stages so you can rollback to an earlier version, you can try new ideas without changing your main application and it can be used as an easy way of uploading your application to any number of servers. As for the database portion, this is a prime example of why you might use `Migrations` in `Laravel`. Have a look at `Git` and then at a later date maybe `Git Flow`